# Create JSON from joined tables

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

How do I create JSON(B) from this statement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar
  USING (id)
```

My solution currently looks like this:

```sql
SELECT to_jsonb(foo) || coalesce(to_jsonb(bar), '{}')
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar
  USING (id)
```

This becomes uglier for every joined table, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT to_jsonb(foo) || coalesce(to_jsonb(bar), '{}') || coalesce(to_jsonb(baz), '{}')
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar
  USING (id)
LEFT JOIN baz
  USING (id)
```

I'd like something like this:

```sql
SELECT to_jsonb(*)
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar
  USING (id)
```

But that gives me:

> [42883] ERROR: function to_jsonb() does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third query produces the cartesian product of all rows from `bar` and `baz` with the same `id`. Regardless whether it is intended, you can use a derived table, moving the conversion to JSON to the outer query.

```
select to_jsonb(q)
from (
    select *
    from foo
    left join bar using(id)
    left join baz using(id)
    ) q
```